# Spring 16 Tooling API v36 - TraceFlag vs DebugLevel bug?

Tags: tooling-api, documentation, spring16

Can anyone enlighten me - what is the purpose of **DebugLevelId** on Tooling API [TraceFlag](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_traceflag.htm) object?

If it is now a required field then what is the purpose of all log level fields (e.g. ApexCode, ApexProfiling, etc) on TraceFlag ?

Contrary to the documentation DebugLevelId appears to be a required value.
If I try to insert TraceFlag without DebugLevelId then SFDC returns error

> DebugLevelId is required

However, with `TraceFlag.DebugLevelId` specified, it seems that whatever Log Levels are set on DebugLevel they take precedence over values set on Trace Flag.

For example
If I create DebugLevel record with `ApexCode = DEBUG` and assign Id of that DebugLevel record to a TraceFlag record with `ApexCode = FINE` then value from Debug Level seems to take precedence.

In the past (API v34) it was possible to create `TraceFlag` on its own (without DebugLevel), now (API v36) there seem to be no way to create `TraceFlag` without `DebugLevelId`, and log level values (e.g. ApexCode, ApexProfiling, System, etc) on `TraceFlag` are simply ignored.

Is this a bug or I am simply missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a change made in Winter '16 (v35.0) - [Release notes Salesforce Winter ’16 Release Notes](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_forcecom_debugging.htm).

As you found, the DebugLevel is now required and takes precedence over the TraceFlag defined levels. I've just gone with the change and used a DebugLevel that gets inserted/updated (upsert didn't work at the time) before the TraceFlag is created.

---

I haven't revisited it, but at the time if two developers opened the developer console at the same time they would be sharing a single DebugLevel record.
[Salesforce Debug logs with the Winter '16 Developer Console](http://www.fishofprey.com/2015/10/salesforce-debug-logs-with-winter-16.html)

Comment: Hello Daniel, thank you for the information and links, they were helpful. By the way - it looks like Debug values (e.g. `ApexCode = FINE`) set on TraceFlag are no longer relevant and do not have to be set because they are overridden by those set on DebugLevel. Is this your observation as well? I did a couple of tests and it seem that way.

Comment: @gaiser Yes, I've found the DebugLevel takes precedence. Somewhere was a page or blog post that explains the order that logging is applied, but I can't find it.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation Daniel. If you come across that blog post please post it here if that's not too much trouble. The answer may benefit from it.

Comment: Found the post I was thinking of - [Does the Summer ’15 release remove the ability to set test logging levels with the DebuggingHeader?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/77645/102). Basically the TraceFlags override the DebuggingHeader on the request.

Comment: Hello Daniel, thank you for the link. It has actually answered two of my questions at once. The other one (which I did not explicitly ask here) is - why DebuggingHeader seem to make no difference with Tooling API. Now I know. Shame about the loss of DebuggingHeader capability with Tooling API.